# phpmyadmin import error

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

Please help.

I need to import database in phpmyadmin ( Cpanel ). But when I do that error shows

```
ALTER TABLE `wp_options`
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (`option_id`),
    ADD UNIQUE KEY `option_name` (`option_name`);
```

> ERROR #1062 - Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

And table `wp_option` has a lot of rows with id 0. On my site on front page are only navigation and all categories work except front page. I also tried to import only wp_options table but everything is same.

When I do the same thing in my localhost ( xampp ) everything is OK and works fine.

Is it possible that this is because different versions of phpmyadmin? And how can I solve it?

localhost in my PC: phpMyAdmin Version information: 4.5.1, latest stable version: 4.6.3

Cpanel: phpMyAdmin Version information: 4.0.10.14

Comment: Seems like your table has duplicates in the option_id  column. A primary key can't have duplicates. Find these duplicates. Update/delete. Add pk.

Comment: is `option_id` autoincrement?

Comment: You are getting the errors because there are already entries present in the table and the import query is trying to overwrite the primary key values. I would suggest you to drop the tables if possible, and then try importing the database as a fresh

Comment: option_id is AUTO_INCREMENT, when I tried to export only table from localhost ( table is ok, without 0 ids ) and import it the same error shows.

Comment: option_id is NOT AUTO_INCREMENT, but I cannot change it becouse of duplicate posts

Answer (score 0):

There exists a table already with the same name. You just need to drop that one and then try to import.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new database, username and password. And try to import.

Answer (score 0):

when you upload the database so select your compatible mode. Let's say your database is MySQL so when you upload it select the compatible mode "MySQL" and this error will disappear and will not cause any error after uploading your database